# What is the difference between bool_or and bool_and

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know the difference between `bool_or` and `bool_and` in PostgreSQL.

For example, what is the difference between

```
select bool_or(start_date > CURRENT_DATE) AS isActive
```

and

```
select bool_and(start_date > CURRENT_DATE) AS isActive
```

Thanks!

Comment: One's an `or` and one's an `and`? I don't understand how you come to write this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both are aggregate functions and operate on multiple rows, not just a single expression.

Consider the following query:

```
with sample_data (id, start_date) as (
   values 
      (1, current_date - 1), 
      (2, current_date + 1) 

)
select bool_or(start_date > CURRENT_DATE) AS or_result,
       bool_and(start_date > CURRENT_DATE) AS and_result
from sample_data;
```

The above returns:

```
or_result | and_result
----------+----------
true      | false
```

`sample_data` contains two rows, one fulfills the condition `start_date > CURRENT_DATE` the other doesn't. `bool_and()` thus returns false because not all of the values fulfill the condition. `bool_or()` returns true because for at least one row the condition is true.

The result of `bool_and()` for the above query is equivalent to:

```
select    (select start_date > current_date from sample_data where id = 1) 
      AND (select start_date > current_date from sample_data where id = 2);
```

Now imagine you would need to write that for a million rows - that's what `bool_and()` and `bool_or()` are for.

Answer (score 2):

From the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) :

> bool_and(expression) : true if all input values are true, otherwise false
>
> bool_or(expression) : true if at least one input value is true, otherwise false

Comment: what do you mean by all inputs ? inputs i put inside the parentheses?

Comment: I think [this page](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/241-True-or-False-every-which-way.html) explain it quite well. Inputs are what you select, what you put inside the parentheses are some kind of conditions / expressions

Answer (score 1):

```
bool_and returns true if all the values are matching on the contrary, 
bool_or returns true if single value is matched.
```

Find more details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html). Hope this helps!

**Edit 1**

In your query conditions in the block states that it will return true/false from single condition (so both the conditions will work as same, as these statements works on multiple rows and not the single statement), so both the expressions will work based on conditions satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I constructed a very intuitive demo.

```
WITH cte (
    start_date
) AS (
    VALUES ('2022-11-01'::date),
        ('2022-11-02'),
        ('2022-11-03'),
        ('2022-11-04'))
SELECT
    start_date,
    bool_and(start_date > CURRENT_DATE) OVER w,
    bool_or(start_date > CURRENT_DATE) OVER w
FROM cte
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY start_date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING);
```

as today is 2022-11-01(YYYY-MM-DD).
it returns:

```
 start_date | bool_and | bool_or
------------+----------+---------
 2022-11-01 | f        | f
 2022-11-02 | f        | t
 2022-11-03 | t        | t
 2022-11-04 | t        | t
(4 rows)
```

the window frame is current row and the next following rows order by start_date asc order.

So bool_and will check if in the frame (window clause), both row meet the condition (start_date > CURRENT_DATE) or not. if meet  then true else false.
It will only evaulate non-null input values.